# Apache Camel timer: "period" vs "fixedRate"

Tags: apache-camel

What is the exact use of "period" and "fixedRate" together ? does it really make sense because if i specified the "period" value then anyways timer will trigger after that interval. So **what is the exact use of "fixedRate" flag**?

I am confused please help me out !

Answer (score 3):

You can read the javadoc api of the java.util.Timer at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

They explain the difference between fixed rate and delayed.

Comment: It's different from Camel timer!

Answer (score 2):

The Camel Timer Endpoint uses `java.util.Timer`.

If you set the `fixedRate` flag to `true` the following method is used :

`java.util.Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)`

Otherwise the following method is used :

`java.util.Timer#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)`

---

If I understand the [Javadoc of the Timer class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html) a fixed-rate execution does not care about the execution time of the previous execution, only of the initial execution.

An example to clarify :

Take a timer with a fixed-rate execution with an initial execution at 12:00 and a period of 1 hour. The timer will (try to) start a third execution at 14:00 - even if, for some reason, the execution which should have started at 13:00 was delayed and actually started at 13:06.

If the timer did **not** have a fixed-rate execution it would (try to) start the third execution at 14:06.