# Infinite loop in Apache Camel

Tags: recursion, apache-camel, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, integration-patterns

I need to create a route, which periodically calls some process with a small delay between iterations.

When I look at documentation for looping:

> The Loop allows for processing a message **a number of times**, possibly in a different way for each iteration. Useful mostly during testing.

So this is not useful for me, since I need to do an infinite loop (without the `CamelLoopSize` explicitly specified).

My second idea was using kind of a "recursion":

```
from("direct:updateLoop").routeId("updateLoop")
  .process(someProcess)
  ...
  .filter(someFilter)  // Can be used to stop the workflow
  .delay(18000000)  // Wait 5 hours and start again
  .to("direct:updateLoop")
```

This works well for a few days, however after about 600 iterations, this fails with `StackOverflowException`

Is there a better way to run my process in an infinite loop?

Comment: Why not to use quartz or timer component?

Comment: Because I cannot determine in advance how long it will take the process to be finished. The process can take few minutes or few days to be done. When I set up just a timer, there will be a possibility of concurrent processing of the same data set. Setting-up a delay simply fits better for my use case.

Comment: How about polling consumer pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Camel Timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) component:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=false&period=18000000")
     .process(someProcess);
```

If `fixedRate` is false, then no overlapping will occur, see [Apache Camel timer: "period" vs "fixedRate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786173/apache-camel-timer-period-vs-fixedrate)

Answer (score 2):

For recursion you can use camel's [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) component.

```
from("seda:updateLoop").routeId("updateLoop")
    .process(someProcess)
    ...
    .filter(someFilter)  // Can be used to stop the workflow
    .delay(18000000)  // Wait 5 hours and start again
    .to("seda:updateLoop");
```

Comment: I have upvoted because it is solution for really long processing - I mean I had many data, which were transported using camel from destination A to destination B, until there is something in A.. That caused stackoverflow, just because the stack was too long (without recursion!)